# How to launch MAUI application from a .NET 7 iOS Application

Tags: c#, ios, .net, maui, deep-linking

I'm looking to launch a .NET MAUI application from a .NET 7 iOS application. I am also expecting the launched application to return data.

I'm using

```
if(UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(new NSUrl("urlScheme://")))
{
     UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("urlScheme://"));
}
```

I'd like to clarify: under which key in the info.plist of the MAUI app should this urlScheme be specified? One article mentioned LSApplicationQueriesSchemes. I tried that but then this if condition returns false stating that the app cannot open an app with this scheme.

Comment: What does the "launch a .NET MAUI application from a .NET 7 iOS application" mean? Do you want to launch the MAUI application form another application in the ios?

Comment: We are in the process of migrating from Xamarin. As first cut we have converted our platform projects to .NET 7 SDK style Android and iOS applications. We are not moving to MAUI yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If App A needs to call App B, then in B's `info.plist` you need to declare:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
   <dict>
     <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
         <array>
              <string>targetapp</string>
         </array>
   </dict>
</array>
```

In A's info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>targetapp</string>
</array>
```

Then you can use the following in the AppDelegate to launch app B.

```cs
if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(new NSUrl("targetapp://")))
{
     UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("targetapp://"));
}
```

Comment: You have worked the issue out. So you can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) for other people to refer to.